# How to get Int32.MaxValue into a ItemsControl element

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I am trying to put Int32.MaxValue into a ItemsControl using only XAML syntax using this markup:

```
<Grid xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">  
<ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32><x:Static Member="sys:Int32.MaxValue" /></sys:Int32>
</ItemsControl>
```

using Kaxaml, I get an error stating that System.Int32 doesn't have a content property.  Is this possible?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
   <x:Static Member="sys:Int32.MaxValue" />
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: right.  I guess I don't need to wrap it in a <sys:Int32> b/c the static member is already typed.